# All first numbers after some string pattern using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to extract all numbers after string "mystr" and something else. For example if I have string.

```
x <- "This is mystring hola 8 and this yourstring hola 9 and again mystrings op 12."
```

It should return 8 and 12.
In R I tried:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "mystr.*\\d+")
```

Comment: This returns only first number, not all of them

Comment: Well it seems you have multiple `mystr` in your input string. Then you may need to turn your dot-star into its un-greedy version `mystr.*?(\\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract the closest digit chunks after `mystr` using

```
x <- "This is mystring hola 8 and this yourstring hola 9 and again mystrings op 12."
regmatches(x, gregexpr("mystr.*?\\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
# => [[1]]
#    [1] "8"  "12"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/CZ4BZx)

This PCRE regex will match

- `mystr` - `mystr`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\\K` - will omit the text matched so far
- `\\d+` - 1+ digits.

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYpxkz/1).

If you want to use `stringr`, you may use `str_match_all`:

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- "This is mystring hola 8 and this yourstring hola 9 and again mystrings op 12."
> str_match_all(x, "mystr.*?(\\d+)")[[1]][,2]
[1] "8"  "12"
```

were the digits are captured into Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `str_match` is more flexible than `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all("This is mystring hola 8 and this yourstring hola 9 and again mystrings op 12.", 
              "mystring.*?(\\d+)")[[1]][, 2]

[1] "8"  "12"
```