# Regex in R: efficiently extracting text before pattern and number immediatelly after pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Suppose that in R, I have many strings composed of a mixture of words and numbers, with one thing in common: in all strings, there is always a pattern `zzzz` followed by a space then a number of unknown digits.

For instance:

```
x <- "many words, some number like 908, then zzzz 145 and some other numbers like 377 and so on"
```

Then, what I am trying to do is to extract **both** the numbers that come after the recurring pattern `zzzz`, but also the text that comes before it.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216787/all-first-numbers-after-some-string-pattern-using-regex-in-r), I know how to extract the numbers after the pattern:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("zzzz \\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
```

That returns `"145"`, with `x` example above. What I am trying to find is the most **efficient way** (since I have millions of strings to evaluate) to retrieve both the number after the pattern but also the content before it, which means returning the vector:

```
"many words, some number like 908, then " "145"
```

What would be the most efficient way of achieving that in R?

Answer (score 1):

We can extract data in two groups.

1. Everything till `zzzz` pattern
2. Number followed by `zzzz`.

```
strcapture('(.*) zzzz (\\d+)', x, list(col1 = character(), col2 = numeric()))

#                                    col1 col2
#1 many words, some number like 908, then  145
```

Comment: Thanks! My apologies, just a clarification: there is not always a number before the pattern. So I think that can be further simplified, right?

Comment: ok, this works **really** well, thanks. One curiosity for learning purposes: (if it is worth a new question please let me know and I will post it): is it possible to adapt that solution to more than one pattern check? I mean, suppose that in different strings there were both `zzzz ` and `xyz ` before the desired numbers. I can find those numbers with, let's say, `'(.*) zzzz (\\d+) | (.*) xyz (\\d+)'. But here, that understandably throws the error `The number of captures in 'pattern' != 'length(proto)'`.

Comment: You can make the second pattern optional with this pattern : `'(.*) zzzz (?:xyz\\s)?(\\d+)'` So here `'xyz\\s'` is non-capturing group which is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit` and `sub`:

```r
x <- "many words, some number like 908, then zzzz 145 and some other numbers like 377 and so on"
parts <- strsplit(x, "\\bzzzz\\s+")[[1]]
parts[2] <- sub("\\s+.*$", "", parts[2])
parts

[1] "many words, some number like 908, then "
[2] "145"
```